# Prove that the rings $R[x]$ and $R[x^2]$ are ring-isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $x$ be an indeterminate. Prove that the rings $R[x]$ and $R[x^2]$ are ring-isomorphic. I don't know if my solution below is too simplistic.

Define a mapping $\varphi :R[x]\rightarrow R[x^2]$ with $f(x)=a_n x^n + \ldots + a_1x + a_0\in R[x]$ such that $\varphi (f(x))=a_n x^{2n}+\ldots +a_1 x^2+a_0$.

Then this mapping is onto homomorphism with kernel being $0$.

So by first isomorphism theorem, $R[x]$ is isomorphic to $R[x^2]$. Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct, but you may want to elaborate on why this is a homomorphism. I think the kernel being zero and surjectivity are obvious enough.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. It's straightforward if you think about it but at the same time, it is subtle.

Comment: @Alan This is not correct, since $x^2$ is not a variable, and $R[x^2]$ here doesn't mean a polynomial ring. It is the subalgebra generated by $x^2$, so surely we have a surjective homomorphism $R[x] \to R[x^2]$, $x \mapsto x^2$, but one has to prove that it is injective, i.e. that $x^2$ is transcendental over $R$. It's easy, sure.

Comment: @John You can use the universal property of the polynomial algebra to construct the homomorphism.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your response but I don't know subalgebra. Can you explain in terms of injective, surjective properties of isomorphism?